# Elastic Search - manipulate final result

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an elastic search index with a structure similar to this one (keep in mind that this is just an example to ilustrate my needs, because the real structure is much more complex):

```
{
  "name" : "Some product name",
  "price" : 999.99,
  "stores" : {
    "Store A" : {
      "quantity" : 2
    },
    "Store B" : {
      "quantity" : 17
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this structure is not compatible with our current needs, so we created a new index, with the structure being something along this lines:

```
{
  "name" : "Some product name",
  "stores" : {
    "Store A" : {
      "quantity" : 2,
      "price" : 1050
    },
    "Store B" : {
      "quantity" : 17,
      "price" : 979.99
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, we moved the a field that was on the root of our entity, to an inner field. In this example, the "price" may be distinct along stores.

Now, I need to add this older data to the new index. To do so, the first thing I need to do is create a query that searches in this old index, and moves the field in the root to the inner field, but I'm new to Elastic, and it's documentation is so extensive I coudn't find something along this lines.

So, my question is: how do I create a query that searches an index, but returns a field that's in the root inside another field?

```
{
  "name" : "Some product name",
  "price" : 999.99,      <----- It should's show it here
  "stores" : {
    "Store A" : {
      "quantity" : 2,
      "price" : 999.99  <----- but here
    },
    "Store B" : {
      "quantity" : 17,
      "price" : 999.99  <----- and here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are going to reindex to a new index, I think it's better to create a pipeline to make this field change.  do you think about using reindex or will you manage the indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script fields query and get the result you want. Here is an example:

```
PUT test_manipulate_response_body/_doc/1
{
  "name" : "Some product name",
  "stores" : {
    "Store C" : {
      "quantity" : 2,
      "price" : 1050
    },
    "Store D" : {
      "quantity" : 17,
      "price" : 979.99
    }
  }
}

GET test_manipulate_response_body/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "store_prices": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "def store_prices = [:]; for (store in params._source.stores.keySet()) { if (params._source.stores[store].containsKey('price')) { store_prices[store] = params._source.stores[store].price; } } return store_prices;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test_manipulate_response_body",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "fields": {
      "store_prices": [
        {
          "Store C": 1050,
          "Store D": 979.99
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

---

---

---

Additional notes: you can get the output format as YAML.

```
GET test_manipulate_response_body/_search?format=yaml
{
  "script_fields": {
    "store_prices": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "def store_prices = [:]; for (store in params._source.stores.keySet()) { if (params._source.stores[store].containsKey('price')) { store_prices[store] = params._source.stores[store].price; } } return store_prices;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response:

```
---
took: 0
timed_out: false
_shards:
  total: 1
  successful: 1
  skipped: 0
  failed: 0
hits:
  total:
    value: 1
    relation: "eq"
  max_score: 1.0
  hits:
  - _index: "test_manipulate_response_body"
    _id: "1"
    _score: 1.0
    fields:
      store_prices:
      - Store C: 1050
        Store D: 979.99
```